# Seperating data sent by iot device before storing in aws dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis, aws-iot

i trying implement a particular functionality for storing iot data in aws dynamodb.
The structure of JSON data that the device will send is in this way:

```
{'deviceid':123,'time':[t1,t2,t3,t4,t5],'voltage':[v1,v2,v3,v4,v5]}
```

Every voltage value is corresponding to its time value. I want it to be stored in dynamodb in this format

| Device_ID | Time | Voltage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | t1 | v1 |
| 123 | t2 | v2 |
| 123 | t3 | v3 |
| 123 | t4 | v4 |
| 123 | t5 | v5 |

I will use device_id and time as my primary key and sort key. A little help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Is the device transmitting to IoT core yet? How/where are you receving that data?

Comment: What part of the process do you need help with?  Parsing JSON? Connecting to DDB?

Comment: Can you provide the access pattern you are trying to meet?  That will be helpful to fully understand the data modelling you'll want to use here.

Comment: @RodrigoM I am currently testing the method. Yes device will send data to iot core and it will send data in the format that I mentioned in the question. I do believe that I can invoke aws lambda from iot rules and then use labmda to separate data.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan Parsing JSON.

Comment: @PeterWagener Actually data sent by devices will be used for analytics purposes. So I will use AWS Glue to transfer data from dynamodb to s3 and convert its format to parquet. If there is a better way of achieving this then I would love to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda is best suited here. Read the JSON data in lambda and save it on the DynamoDB like you which. Plain JSON processing and DynamoDb api call should be good enough

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are collecting data from IoT devices, and the current setup with dynamodb works well. But you should also consider other options as Kinesis Firehose/Streams for cost efficiency and performance both.

Assuming you will have lots of data points coming in from the devices, that will result in huge volume of data. Dynamodb is well performant nosql database, but it might be quite expensive solution in long run. Especially Writes are quite expensive in Dynamodb and so is the scan queries.

An alternative design could be:

```
IoT Core -> Kinesis Firehose(+ record transformation lambda) -> S3 buckets
```

You can send the events to Kinesis Firehose. Since you would like to split the records in multiple records, you can implement a lambda function and invoke that inside the firehose  transformation. You can define the target as S3 destination and select the data format as parquet/ORC and the compression technique.